# FileUtils (Apache IO)

Tags: потоки-данных, java

Я использую `FileUtils.copyURLToFile(URL, File)` для загрузки аудиозаписей в своей программе. Как мне отобразить прогресс загрузки файла?

На данный момент у меня после старта загрузки запускаются два потока так: `Thread t = new Thread()..`. Один загружает собственно, а другой, пока "жив" первый, считает процент выполнения и выводит его на экран. Но уж больно мне это не нравится.

Хотел сделать это с помощью SwingWorker, но понял, что `FileUtils.copyURLToFile(URL, File)` все равно не даст мне показывать прогресс `publish()`, пока не закончится загрузка. Как быть?

Послушал совет [[@a_gura](/users/1439/a_gura)](/users/1439/a_gura).

Сделал так:

```
URL u = new URL(url);

                    URLConnection connection = u.openConnection();   
                    connection.setReadTimeout(2000);
                    BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());                      
                    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(destination);   
                    long b = connection.getContentLength();

                    byte[] buf = new byte[4096];
                    int len;
                    while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
                        out.write(buf, 0, len);

                        String song = d.artist + " - "+ d.title;
                        long percent = destination.length()*100/b;

                        window.downloadProcess.setText(percent + " %");
                    }
                    out.close();
                    destination.setLastModified(connection.getLastModified());
                    in.close();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C `FileUtils.copyURLToFile` вы этого никак не сделаете. Посмотрите в код этого метода, он очень простой. В конце концов непосредственно скачивание происходит в методе `IOUtils.copyLarge`. Это простой цикл. Напишите свой аналогичный код и в зависимости от количества скачанных байтов расчитывайте и отображайте прогресс загрузки.